# wchar_t to std::string in hex format

Tags: c++, string, char, std, wchar

I'm trying to convert a `wchar_t` to a hexadecimal and then convert it to `std::string`.

Here is my code:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::clog << wchar << std::endl;
#endif

    wchar_t wideChar = printf("0x%x", wchar);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::clog << wideChar << std::endl;
#endif

    std::string str = "";
    str.assign(wideChar, 4);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::clog << str << std::endl;
#endif
```

wchar is a variable of type wchar_t and it has a dynamic value. I'm using the value 69 in this example which is the equivalent of the E key.

First I'm converting the wchar to another wchar_t and this wideChar holds the hexadecimal value. This works like expected except it has one more character I don't need/want.

At the end I'm trying to convert the wide char to string and this fails horribly. The idea behind this is I only need the first 4 letters of the hexadecimal number (like 0x45 not 0x454).

Example Output:

```
69
0x454
♦♦♦♦
```

The biggest problem I have is that the string only has this weird symbols in it. I want to convert the wchar to string exactly how it is but I want to remove the last character.

The desired output should be:

```
69
0x454
0x45
```

Can someone tell me what my code is doing wrong and how I can do it right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wchar_t wideChar = printf("0x%x", wchar);`? What? `printf`returns the number of characters transmitted to the output stream.

Comment: Which platform? Note `wchar_t` has 16 bits on Windows and 32 on POSIX.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/WqxcrW4dr

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
str.assign(wideChar, 4);
```

uses this overload:

```
constexpr basic_string& assign( size_type count, CharT ch );
```

Since you assigned the number of characters transmitted to `stdout` in

```
wchar_t wideChar = printf("0x%x", wchar);
```

to `wideChar`, then `wideChar` is `4` (`0x45` makes it 4 characters).

So, you assign four `char(4)`s to the string, making it `"\004\004\004\004"`.